# How to copy all attributes and functions in a class instance to another class in python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

Suppose that we have an **instance** of an unknown class.

```
parent=Unknown()
```

This object is not necessarily an instance of a specific class (it might be an instance of any classes but I know the name of potential classes). I want to define a new class to inherit the attributes and functions of that object. Since I do not know what is the class of this instance, I cannot use python class inheritances. I know that if the parent class was known, we could use the following code:

```
class Child(Unknown)
     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
```

But in my case, I do not know what is the parent class, and I just have an instance of it. So I want to do such a thing:

```
class Child()
     def __init__(self, parent):
         super().__init__()
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

this will set every attribute of an instance of a class (`parent`) to the same-named attribute in a class called `Child`. Note that it will only change attributes in the class `dict`.

```
child = Child()
for att, value in parent.__dict__.items():
    setattr(child, att, value)
```

You can change almost ALL attributes with this (`__weakref__`), for example will not be change):

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = None

a = Test()
a.t = 'set t'
a.b = 'set b'

class Test2():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

child = Test2()
for att in dir(a):
    try:
        setattr(child, att, getattr(a,att))
    except AttributeError:
        continue
```

But, you will also be changing the class of the variable, i.e. `child.__class__ == Test`

Comment: Thank you for your solution. The first answer only copies the properties (class variables not class methods). And the second answer copies all the thinks from "a" and erases the Test2 properties. It even changes the class of object "child" from "Test2" to "Test" which is not what I am looking for.